# Why is $\lim_{x\to\frac\pi2^+}\frac7x\sec x=-\infty$?

Tags: calculus, limits

Why is the below true?
$$\lim_{x\to\frac\pi2^+}\frac7x\sec x=-\infty$$
Do I need to know the graph of the secant function?

Comment: You don't need to, but it couldn't hurt. ;)  You *do* need to know that $\sec(x) = \frac 1{\cos(x)}$, though.

Comment: Can you work out the limits of the factors $7/x$ and $\sec(x)$?

Answer (score 2):

You don't necessarily need to know the graph of secant.

Recall that $\sec(x)=\frac{1}{\cos(x)}$.

Thus:

$$\frac{7}{x}\sec(x)=\frac{7}{x\cos(x)}$$

Using direct substitution:

$$\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}^+}\frac{7}{x\cos(x)}=\frac{14}{\pi}\cdot\frac{1}{\cos(\pi/2)}=\frac{14}{\pi}\cdot\frac{-1}{0}=-\infty$$

Since we are approaching $\pi/2$ from the right, we are approaching $\pi/2$ from the second quadrant, ergo the second expression becomes negative.

Comment: Edited: Accidentally read this as approaching from the left.